# Jquery UI droppable - dynamically created content not responding to events

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, nested, jquery-ui-droppable

Here's my best attempt at describing my challenge. I'm trying to make content wrappers and placeable content (draggable from individually scoped unordered lists) nestable on a virtually infinite level. Currently, the content wrappers nest and float appropriately, but when I try to drag in "content", it ignores the wrappers as being newly created droppable objects.

Here's a [current fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rbtstudio/XWJ7g/3/) of my project.

Might anyone have any suggestions? I've seen solutions leading to a liveQuery plugin and utilizing the .on() event, but with the complexity of my code, I'm not sure where to even incorporate those. Anyone feeling helpful?

Comment: so be able to drag search item 1 into 'new child wrapper' (which i just dragged out there)?

Comment: It worked for you on the fiddle? I've tested in three major browsers on Mac, and neither the Main Wrapper or New Child Wrapper accept Search items as droppables for me...??

Comment: Sorry, I meant that as a question. :) Is the problem that the newly created placeholder is not "droppable" for the dynamic LI's ?

Comment: Yes. When a wrapper is created, it needs to be set dynamically as a new droppable object for the Search Items. The same goes for any nested wrappers... each one needs to be able to have content dropped inside of it. Ideas as to what I'm missing?